# What are the advantages or disadvantages of using iFrames inside iFrames?

Tags: html, web, iframe

**In advantages, I can think of ability to host/embed a third party domain or service.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a disadvantage, that is, it is hard for event handling for the app contained inside an iFrame. It will need to do a *postMessage* on every event, say, scroll or resize.